# Is it better to use a single operation, than multiple?

Tags: optimization, tensorflow

In TensorFlow there are often many ways to do a thing.

For example one to do `x+=b`
one can do a [`assign_add`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign_add), **or** one could do a `add` and a `assign`

There are similar other examples where 2 ops can do the job of one

- `Concat` + `ExpandDims` vs `Stack`
- `scatter_nd_update` multiple times,  vs `scatter_nd_update` all at once by seperately precomputing the index combinations you want to update.
- `add_n` vs n `add`s

Are the single operations fundamentally faster/better?
Or are they their for convenience?

Does using XLA JIT change this?

(Motivation is in defining the overloads in the [Julia binding](https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/issues/221))

Comment: tensorflow is at such a high level, that you really cant form a conclusion..."It depends" is the closes you can get.  You just have to try it for your implementation on that machine on that day.  Add or remove one line of code and expect anywhere from no to a significant performance change even if the line has nothing to do with your critical algorithm.   Basic compiled software stuff...tensorflow is not special in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

In TensorFlow generally a single operation, if available, is more efficient. `x = x + b` often allocates memory for `x + b` and then frees it, while `x += b` has no overhead. Similarly for the many fused kernels in tensorflow, such as those for the softmax losses.

We hope that eventually XLA will get to the point where straightforward code is as efficient as code which minimizes kernels, but that is not always the case as of May 2017.

Comment: For reference, the motivation is: https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/issues/221

Answer (score 0):

Its actually very difficult to tell which is operationally more efficient.

For an example of which is better...

`a = a + b` vs `a += b`

if a given language was written in the assembly code IE mips. the add function of mips is generally of

```
add save_ref, value_ref1, value_ref2
```

so a compiler would write both the given operations as

```
add a, a, b  **or** add a, b, a
```

which are identical. To figure out which is operationally more efficient in TF you would either have to look at the documentation or source code and hope that it elaborates upon the O(n) times.

Calling the single `scatter_nd_update` might be marginally faster as you might save space on the stack as calling a method has some very small marginal cost. Most likely the cost is negligible.

Comment: This doesn't seem like anything but speculation, and expanding upon the very thing I am asking. I'm not sure this is an answer. except the last paragraph, which even then is basically a guess (and is phrased as such).

Comment: Well there frankly just isn't anyway to know unless you have access to the source code and/or if the documentation states otherwise.

Comment: I don't dispute this. But we *do* have access to the source, it is on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow). I'm hoping for an answer from someone familiar with the implementation.